# Laravel Error: the requested PHP extension sqlite3 is missing from your system

Tags: php, composer-php

I just downloaded a project from server for modifications. When I entered the path 'http://localhost/zcart/public' (which is the local path of the project directory) an installer page occured. It is saying that sqlite3 extension is not there.

I just tried to run the composer through terminal and executed command 'composer install', but it just gave me an error **the requested PHP extension sqlite3 is missing from your system.**
Here is the SS:
[image: Terminal Error]

I'm stuck in this issue for a while. Any suggestions will be highly appreciated. I'll be happy to provide any sorts of details if needed.
Here is the installer screenshot:
[image: Installer Error]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to enable SQLite3 extension in xampp. Open `xampp/php/php.ini` and find it:

```
;extension=sqlite3
```

Then un-comment the line (remove `;`)

```
extension=sqlite3
```

Save the `php.ini` and restart your Xampp server.